# how to route local ip subnet to vpnc tunnel

Tags: linux, route, iproute

I have a `vpnc` client that will connect to Cisco and I put any information to `/etc/vpnc/default` then I run `vpnc-connect` status connected. All routes will be replaced to `tun0`.

The targeted `10.10.0.9` can be ping'd from this host. This host has the private IP `10.10.2.15/24` and others host `10.10.2.x/24`, I made route in other host with iproute `ipr a a 10.10.0.9 via 10.10.2.15`. But can't ping `10.10.0.9`.

Edit : 
ip a

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
link/ether 00:06:5b:3c:2b:3a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.10.2.15/24 brd 10.10.8.255 scope global eth3
inet6 fe80::206:5bff:fe3c:2b3a/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
14: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1412 qdisc
pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 500
link/[65534]
inet 10.103.56.242/32 scope global tun0
```

edit : 
ip r

```
180.214.x.x via 10.10.2.1 dev eth1  src 10.10.2.15  mtu 1500 advmss 1460
10.10.2.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.10.2.15
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth1  scope link  metric 1003
default dev tun0  scope link
```

[image]

edit :
mtr 10.10.0.9

```
Keys:  Help   Display mode   Restart statistics   Order of fields   quit
                                          Packets               Pings
Host                                       Loss%  Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
1. 10.10.2.15                               0.0%   0.3   0.4   0.3   0.5   0.1
2. ???
```

Comment: I offered an edit which edits the formatting a bit to make things more readable, and I attempted to make things clearer; but I do not know there are several sentences which I still cannot interpret. Can you try to elaborate any more?

Comment: Is there any connection between the two paragraphs? Is `10.10.2.15` a VPN IP? Can `10.10.2.x` reach `10.10.0.9`? If you have such a network question then always provide the outputs of `ip addr` and `ip route`.

Comment: @HalosGhost sorry i write on mobile, i do not know how to formatting yet.

Comment: @HaukeLaging yes. Vpn ip is 10.10.2.15 and other in same network. 10.10.2.x can't reach 10.10.0.9 even i have routed to vpn ip as gateway. vpn ip reached.

Comment: @Pathic, that's perfectly fine. I'm less worried about the formatting than about what your actual question was.

Comment: In this case, i wanna ask there is any specific configuration in vpnc to route other ip addr in same network to vpnc tunnel ?

Comment: Could you please post the output of *ip addr show* and of *ip route show*? Thank you.

Comment: @Pathic First you need a system which can reach both `10.10.0.9` and `10.10.2.15` directly over one of its links. **After** that you can care about the routing on `10.10.2.15`.

Comment: @HaukeLaging yes from vpn ip connected already. Then i route from other host where target is 10.10.0.9 via 10.10.2.15

Comment: Have you turned on IP forwarding on 2.15? (e.g., `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` and/or `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/DEV/forwarding`)

Answer (score 1):

The `via` address in an `ip route` command is obviously the gateway address i.e. the system on the same link which the packet is sent to. There is a `src` option to `ip route` which can define the source address but that is usually not needed.

Comment: routing in 10.10.2.x have 2 route default route (0.0.0.0/0 via 10.10.2.1) and specific route (10.10.0.9 via 10.10.2.15)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your response, I'm very appreciated it.

After I test several route with  ip route, then I found the route for each server.
At 10.10.2.20 just add,

```
ip r a 10.10.0.90 via 10.10.2.15 dev eth1
```

and 10.10.2.15 just add,

```
ip r a 10.10.0.9 dev tun0
```

result :

```
Keys:  Help   Display mode   Restart statistics   Order of fields   quit
                                            Packets                  Pings
 Host                                       Loss%  Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
 1. 10.10.2.15                               0.0%   0.4   0.5   0.4   0.6   0.1
 2. 10.1.4.165                               0.0%   2.8   3.2   2.6   4.3   0.8
 3. 10.1.4.129                               0.0%  39.5  30.3   2.8  48.7  24.3
 4. ???
 5. 10.10.0.126                              0.0%   4.1   4.4   4.1   5.1   0.6
 6. 10.10.0.9                                0.0%   3.5   4.2   3.5   5.5   1.1
```